# How to convert QString to jstring?

Tags: c++, qt, java-native-interface, qstring

I tried the following code to convert QString to jstring according to PaulMcKenzie's answer.

```
jstring CreateJStringFromQString(JNIEnv *env, const QString& str)
{
    jstring js = env->NewString(reinterpret_cast<jchar *>(str.data()), str.size());
    return js;
}
```

But , I have the following error

```
/home/runner/work/jni/jni/hello/src/main/cpp/HelloJNIImpl.cpp:46:69: 
error: reinterpret_cast from type ‘const QChar*’ to type ‘jchar*’ 
{aka 
‘short unsigned int*’} casts away qualifiers
46 |     jstring js = env->NewString(reinterpret_cast<jchar *> 
(str.data()), str.size());
                                                                       
          ^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

[image]

I tried that answer . But it comes the above error.

How to convert QString to jstring ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Qt, so I am going by the documentation [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#data) with regards to QString.

Given that, you can try the following:

```
jstring CreateJStringFromQString(JNIEnv *env, const QString& str)
{
    jclass string_class = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
    jmethodID string_constructor = env->GetMethodID(string_class, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V" );
    jstring js = env->NewObject(string_class, string_constructor, env->NewString(str.data(), str.size()));
    return js;
}
```

I use code similar to the above in the JNI interfaces I've written.

There is no error checking to see if the `string_class` and `string_constructor` are valid, but assume they are.

Basically you have to construct a java `String` object, and populate it with the data.

Comment: If `QString` follows how `std::string` has move semantics, changing to `const` reference may not result in a speedup.  Given that, basically `std::string`'s are now being passed by value for code that's C++ 11 compliant and above in many codebases.

Comment: Looks like `QString` does have move semantics: `QString(QString &&other)` -- so passing by value should not have a performance hit.

Comment: `NewString` constructs a Java `String` with the given contents, so calling `NewObject` seems kind of redundant.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I edited my question. sorry for the delay.

Comment: If both QChar and jchar are 16-bit `int` characters (and it looks like they are), then the issue maybe of `signed` versus `unsigned`.  If that's the cast simply applying a `reinterpret_cast<jchar *>` should work, i.e. `env->NewString(reinterpret_cast<jchar *>(str.data()), str.size());`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think a const reference is preferred in this case, as it guaranties that no copy will be made of `str` in this case. Note that `QString` also has Copy-On-Write behavior. So if you pass `str` non-const, you should at least use `constData` instead of `data` to prevent a copy from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Since Qt 6.1 you can use [QJniObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qjniobject.html#object)

If you need only temporary `jstring` e.g. to pass argumment to jni function call, then you can use such a conversion:

```
QJniObject::fromString(your_QString).object<jstring>()
```

But as mentioned in Qt documentation you need to be aware of string lifetime being bound to scope of owning QJniObject.